# Android run-time permissions -- user granting permission, not receiving it in onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: java, android, permissions

I'm trying to set up my app to use run-time permissions. I've got the request dialog showing alright, but when I choose "Accept" on the dialog, and onRequestPermissionsResult is called, grantResults do not show PERMISSION_GRANTED, and the app doesn't get the permissions. Here is how I'm requesting the permission:

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) contnext,
     new String[]{Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
     MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

And the callback:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // do good stuff
                Log.i("net.bradmont.prayson", "Permissions granted by user");
            } else {
                Log.i("net.bradmont.prayson", "Permissions refused by user");
                Log.i("net.bradmont.prayson", "grantResults.length " + grantResults.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                Log.i("net.bradmont.prayson", "grantResults[" + i +"]" + grantResults.length);
                }
                Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(mCoordinator, 
                        R.string.cant_open_file_no_permission, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar1.show();
            }

    }
}
```

The result is that after accepting the permissions dialog, the app shows the error snackbar. Here's what shows in logcat:

```
net.bradmont.prayson  I  Permissions refused by user
                      I  grantResults.length 2
                      I  grantResults[0]2
                      I  grantResults[1]2
```

I can't even figure out what 2 would signify in grantResults; the only consts with a value of 2 in the PackageManager documentation are COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED and GET_RECEIVERS.

What on earth is going on here?

Comment: Get rid of `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` -- since you cannot hold that permission anyway -- and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're printing the length of `int[] grantResults` over and over in the loop instead of the values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
      Log.i("net.bradmont.prayson", "grantResults[" + i +"]" + grantResults.length);
}
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
      Log.i("net.bradmont.prayson", "grantResults[" + i +"]" + grantResults[i]);
}
```

Secondly, as CommonsWare stated `Manifest.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` is `Protection level: signature`, which means `This permission cannot be granted to third-party apps.` see the [documentation for MANAGE_DOCUMENTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MANAGE_DOCUMENTS).

Since your first request is `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`, not wonder the first value in `grantResults` is not `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`. I'm going to guess the second value is actually `PERMISSION_GRANTED` corresponding to the `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` request.

Long story short, get rid of the `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` request:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
     new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
     MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```